# SQL запрос в PosgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Непонятно как сослаться на отдельное поле связанной внешним ключём таблицы чтобы оформить запроc: "Вывести полную информацию о водителях и их заработке за последнюю неделю".

Пытаюсь оформить запрос

```
SELECT soname, name, nation, birthdate, years_drive, zakaz.driver.avto.brand AS avto, (drivers.zakaz.len*avto.tarif) AS zarobotok FROM drivers, avto, zakaz WHERE zakaz.date > '01.01.1800' ORDER BY drivers.soname;
```

но выдает ошибку несвязанных таблиц... Хотя по внешним ключам связей достаточно!

*Как правильно составить запрос?*

В базе есть такие таблицы:

**drivers**

```
 taxi=# select * from drivers;

 person_sid |         name         |        soname        | birthdate  | years_drive |        nation        | avto | zakaz
------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+------+-------
          2 | Наташа               | Королаева            | 1975-02-10 |          20 | таджики              |    2 |     2
          5 | Валико               | Медленидзе           | 1912-06-11 |          75 | грузин               |    1 |     1
         10 | Егор                 | Иванов               | 1970-09-05 |          10 | рус                  |    6 |     4
          1 | Игорь                | Николаев             | 1960-01-01 |          30 | рус                  |    5 |     5
          9 | Виктория             | Логинова             | 1995-08-12 |          15 | таджики              |    9 |     6
          6 | Курбан               | Байрамов             | 1982-07-22 |          15 | таджики              |    6 |     9
          3 | Михаель              | Шумахер              | 1965-03-20 |          35 | поляки               |    4 |    10
          4 | Гойко                | Митич                | 1962-05-05 |          25 | поляки               |    7 |     1
          7 | Юлия                 | Меньшова             | 1982-07-22 |          15 | таджики              |   10 |     7
          8 | Самуил               | Оганезов             | 1982-07-22 |          15 | таджики              |    8 |     8
```

**avto**

```
taxi=# select * from avto;
 avto_id |        brand         | odometer | tarif
---------+----------------------+----------+-------
       1 | Волга                |   100000 |    10
       2 | Нива                 |   150000 |    10
       3 | Москвич              |   200000 |    10
       4 | Жигули               |   120000 |    10
       5 | Запорожец            |   180000 |    10
       6 | BMW                  |   900000 |    10
       7 | Horh                 |   800000 |    10
       8 | Bentley              |     1000 |   200
       9 | Rolsroys             |      700 |   200
      10 | Maybach              |      500 |   300
```

**zakaz** (стоимость заказа = zakaz.len * avto.tarif)

```
taxi=# select * from zakaz;
 zakaz_id |    date    |  len  | driver | city
----------+------------+-------+--------+------
        1 | 1855-01-12 |  1500 |      1 |   10
        2 | 1942-12-10 |  1600 |      2 |    9
        3 | 1732-10-12 |  1700 |      3 |    8
        4 | 1236-12-02 |  2700 |      4 |    7
        5 | 2542-12-11 |  2800 |      5 |    6
        6 | 1942-12-05 |  3800 |      4 |    5
        7 | 8520-12-03 |  3500 |      5 |    5
        8 | 4150-12-10 |  4500 |      6 |    4
        9 | 2004-12-22 |  4400 |      6 |    1
       10 | 2000-12-18 | 11400 |      2 |    8
```

Comment: Используйте явные [объединения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Answer (score 0):

Запрос будет иметь приблизительно следующий вид -

```
Select soname, name, nation, birthdate, years_drive, a.brand,(d.zakaz.len*a.taris) zarabotok
FROM drivers d
    inner join avto a on d.avto=a.avto_id
    inner join zakaz z on d.zakaz=z.zakaz.id
WHERE zakaz.date > '01.01.1800' 
ORDER BY d.soname;
```

где inner join связь с таблицами